# Why does Docker not allow a mounted directory to contain files which do not exist on the image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In my `project/openresty/conf.d/` I have config and scripts. My config is named default.conf, which is identical to the default.conf that the openresty image comes with. This file works flawlessly.

Any other file I add to this directory, including lua script files, do not show up at all.  They cannot be accessed or read and do not show up on the file explorer.

```
 openresty:
   image: openresty/openresty:latest
   depends_on:
     - sssg_scylla
   restart: always
   volumes:
     - type: bind
       source: openresty/conf.d
       target: /etc/nginx/conf.d
       read_only: true
   ports:
     - "18080:80"
     - "18443:443"
```

I receive no errors or warnings. My files just don't show up. I've restarted docker and everything I can think of. It doesn't matter.

Host machine is Arch Linux. Docker version 24.0.6, build ed223bc820.  Docker Compose version v2.20.0.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] showing how the files do not appear? Include the commands to verify the files exist on the host, the commands and configuration to run the container, and commands showing the files do not exist inside the container.